# Reduce Width: I want to reduce space between 2 tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm creating a react native project. In that project I create tab navigator but one tab taking too much space how can i reduce it?

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
  tabBarOptions={{
    style: { backgroundColor: "#25D366" },
    activeTintColor: colors.white,
    labelStyle: { fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 15 },
    indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: colors.white },
    showIcon: true,
  }}
>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Camera"
    component={Pic}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: () => null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="camera" color={color} size={23} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Status" component={Story} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Calls" component={Call} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

[image]
Can anyone suggest me a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want them to be all the same size, you can try setting `flexBasis: 1` on the styles for the tabs.

Comment: I only want to change camera

Comment: Could you provide more information? Is the camera tab the one that's too big? If so why wouldn't you just decrease its size?

Comment: well camera tab only contain icon and so there is a lot of space between camera and home tab and i want to reduce that space, only that space

Comment: Still not quite sure what you mean. Maybe post a screenshot? From what you're saying it sounds like a problem with the styling of the camera icon being different from the other tabs.

Comment: i added image in question check it space between camera and home tab is a lot

Comment: Oh, well that's normal, the tabs are equally sized, and the camera icon is not as wide as the labels on the other tabs. You could try to reduce the width of the camera tab through styling, but honestly it looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I know it's too much but i wan to learn how can style a custom tab for that so in future if i need it i must know how to do it, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the tab bar width you have to override default style props using style as following example,

```
<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} style={{width:100px}} />
```

Comment: what are the style props suggest in Tab screen

Comment: tabBarIcon, tabBarLabel, tabBarTestId, tabBarAccessibilityLabel and title